# How to see memory allotment for Docker Engine?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Setting up a docker instance of Elasticsearch Cluster. 
In the instructions it says
  `Make sure Docker Engine is allotted at least 4GiB of memory`

I am ssh'ing to the host, not using docker desktop. 
How can I see the resource allotments from the command line?

reference URL
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html

Comment: I would need more details to answer this question better, but assuming it's a generic non-desktopy Linux, I'm still going to attempt an answer

Comment: You can use `docker system info` or `docker info` to see the resources allotment for CPU, Memory etc.

Comment: `docker system info` gave the 'info' I was looking for
`Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.7
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.49GiB
`

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, with Docker Desktop on Windows 10 while running Linux containers on WSL2.

I found this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/92 and tried to apply similar logic to the solution of there.

I entered the WSL instance's terminal by
`wsl -d docker-desktop` command.
Later I run `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` command to set 'allotted memory'.

After these steps I could run elasticsearch's docker compose example.

Answer (score -2):

I'd like to go about it by just using one command.

```
 docker stats -all
```

This will give a output such as following

```
$ docker stats -all

CONTAINER ID        NAME           CPU%  MEM USAGE/LIMIT   MEM%   NET I/O BLOCK I/O PIDS
5f8a1e2c08ac my-compose_my-nginx_1 0.00% 2.25MiB/1.934GiB 0.11% 1.65kB/0B 7.35MB/0B  2
```

To modify the limits :
when you're making your docker-compose.yml include the following at the end of your file. (if you'd like to set up a 4 GiB limit)

```
resources:
limits:
memory: 4048m
reservations:
memory: 4048m
```

Comment: this gave the resources of currently running containers, which is different from what the article was referring to